# Taylor expansion of the multiplicative inverse of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

The Taylor expansion of a function is given by
$$
f(x) = \sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n(z-a)^n
$$
for $z\in B(a;r)$. Suppose $a_0\neq0$. From this,  we can establish that $1/f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $a$.
Is there a way to obtain a nicer form of the Taylor expansion of $1/f(z)$ and the radius of convergence?

Comment: (1) Are those exponents supposed to be $1$, $2$, and $3$? If so, you don't need parentheses. (2) There is no Taylor expansion for $f(x)$ if $f(0)=0$. (3) If $f(0)\not=0$, then you can get the Taylor expansion for $\displaystyle{1\over f(x)}$ by doing long division.

Comment: No, they are not supposed to be $1,2$ and $3$. They are just some coefficients that appear from the expansion of $f(x)$, and I'm interested in seeing how those coefficients can be used to write the expansion for $1/f(x)$

Comment: So what you meant was $f(x)=a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is a much better way to write it. Thanks.

Comment: As for an answer to your problem, check out the second answer to  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53384/power-series-of-the-reciprocal-does-a-recursive-formula-exist-for-the-coeffic .

Comment: You ask for a "nicer form" of the Taylor expansion of the reciprocal, which suggests that you already have one form of the reciprocal. We can't tell whether another form is nicer, if you don't tell us what form you already have.

Comment: @Oliver, I'm happy to leave it to you. I should have noticed the date on the post.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n (z-a)^n$ and $f(a)=a_0\neq0$. Furthermore, suppose $R>0$  is is the radius of convergence of $f$. Then $g(z)=1/f(z)$ is analytic in a neighborhood $B(a;\rho)\subset B(a;R)$. Suppose
$g(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}b_n(z-a)^n$ on $B(a;\rho)$. Since  $1=f(z)g(z)$, the Cauchy product formula yields
$$\begin{align}
a_0b_0=1\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
0=\sum^n_{k=0}a_kb_{n-k}=a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+\ldots + a_nb_0\tag{2}\label{two}
\end{align}$$
for $n\geq 1$. From \eqref{one} and \eqref{two} we obtained expressions for $b_n$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, recursively to get
$$
\begin{align}
b_0&=\frac{1}{a_0}\tag{1'}\label{onep}\\
b_n&=-\frac{1}{a_0}\big(a_1b_{n-1}+\ldots + a_nb_0\big)\tag{2'}\label{twop}
\end{align}
$$

All one can say about the radius of convergence of the power series $g(z)=\sum_{n\geq0}b_n(z-a)^n$ is that it is positive. Some Cauchy-type estimates for the $b_n$'s can be obtained as follows.
Choose $0<\rho<R$ so that
$$\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}|a_n|\rho^n<|a_0|\tag{3}\label{three}
\end{align}$$
Then,  $|b_n|\leq |b_0|\rho^{-n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$: for $n=0$ this holds trivially; assuming this hols for $0\leq j\leq n-1$, we get from \eqref{twop} that
$$\begin{align}
|b_n|&\leq |b_0|\big(|a_1||b_0|\rho^{-(n-1)}+\ldots +|a_n||b_0|\big)\\
&=\rho^{-n}|b_0|^2\big(|a_1|\rho+\ldots+|a_n|\rho^n\big)\\
&\leq \rho^{-n}|b_0|^2\sum^\infty_{k=1}|a_k|\rho^k\leq |b_0|\rho^{-n}
\end{align}
$$
Consequently, the power series for $g$ converges in $B(a;\rho)$.